# Stop observing changed when template changes

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I **stop** observing changes on a cursor(client side) when the user navigates out of the template?

```
Template.postPage.created = function(){      
var postId = Router.current().params._id;
postCursor = Posts.find(postId);
postHandle = postCursor.observeChanges({
    changed: function(id, fields){
      // actions
    }
  });
};
```

I'm using iron router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the variable to the template instance and stop it when its destroyed:

```
Template.postPage.created = function(){      
    var postId = Router.current().params._id;
    var postCursor = Posts.find(postId);

    this.postHandle = postCursor.observeChanges({
        changed: function(id, fields){
            // actions
        }
    });
};

Template.postPage.destroyed = function() {
    this.postHandle.stop();
}
```

Comment: On some scenarios, you'll need to use ´Template.currentData()´ instead of relaying on the route. But it's a matter of preference I guess.

Comment: `Template.currentData()` gives you the data the template has access to, if you use `this` in the created callback you get the instance of the template unique to that template. If you use currentData there is a chance the variables you assign can lose references when there is a reactive change involved. The best would be this approach or using `Template.instance()` for `this`